# i3: multiple displays; having some "resistance" from mouse pointer when crossing display

Tags: x11, multi-monitor, xrandr, i3

Can X or i3 in particular be configured so that the mouse would not jump immediately to the next display but would require some sort of "time and force" to take place, so that it would be easy to drag selection rectangles on one screen that would not stretch to unrelated area on the next screen by accident?